# T-SQL Duplicate row based on quantity

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I cannot use CTEs in this scenario and was wondering what the best way to create another table that displays an item multiple times (based on it's quantity value).

I.e.

```
Fruit   Quantity
-----------------
Banana     2
Apple      3
```

What I want to be produced:

```
Banana
Banana
Apple
Apple
Apple
```

I created a table with the possible quantities and this is what I've written as a query so far:

```
SELECT a.fruit
FROM fruit a
JOIN numbers n ON a.quantity <= n.number
```

It's not returning the right output for me, do let me know how I can be writing this better.

Again, I am working with T-SQL in a third-party platform where CTEs are not supported.

Comment: Can you also do a `select top 100 * from numbers order by number` for us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `join` condition is backwards.  Try:

```
SELECT f.fruit
FROM fruit f JOIN
     numbers n
     ON n.number <= a.quantity;
```